# How to change array values using php

Tags: php

I have an array. I want to check its elements' values and change them if they are equal to 0 or 0.00
Here's what i tried and failed :

```
foreach($returnArray as $arrayElement){
            if($arrayElement === 0 || $arrayElement === 0.00){
                $arrayElement = null;
            }
        }
```

I wanna change 0 or 0.00 values into null value. $returnArray is my main array, it has some int and double values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one mistake,  `$arrayElement = null;` has scope only within the loop. You need

```
foreach($returnArray as $key=>$arrayElement){
            if($arrayElement == 0 ){
                $returnArray[$key] = null; // This updates the actual array
            }
        }
```

This way you update the actual array elements which will stay that way even after the loop. Using the temporary variable within the loop will not have changes visible outside it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_map()`, and just test each element for a falsey value (both `0` and `0.00` equate to false):

```
$returnArray = array_map(function($a) { return $a ?: null; }, $returnArray);
```

#### [Here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AzdfSp)

Answer (score 2):

PHP passes elements into `foreach` loops as copies. You can [pass the actual element by refence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) like this:

```
foreach($returnArray as &$arrayElement){
    if($arrayElement === 0 || $arrayElement === 0.00){
        $arrayElement = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you enlighten me what do you mean by loops as copies ?

Comment: See my update. When using a `foreach` you are using a copy of the value with a local scope inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

And with:

```
foreach($returnArray as $k => $arrayElement){
            if($arrayElement <= 0){
                $returnArray[$k] = null;
            }
        }
```